# Запись в файл новой строки после вызова функции на С

Tags: c, файлы, строки

Здравствуйте, нужно написать на С функцию, что будет открывать определенный файл и добавлять туда число на 1 больше предыдущего т.е. функция должна считать последнюю строку и добавить на новую строку следующее число.
Например уже были числа(1, 2(с новой строки)) и должно появиться число 3
Либо этих чисел ещё не было в файле.

Мои попытки что-то создать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int id(void)
{
        int i;
        char buff[] = "00001";
        char delim[] = "|";
        char *word;
        FILE *f;
        if ((f = fopen("bd2.txt", "a+"))==NULL)
  {
     fprintf(f, "%s\n", "00000");//но.....нет.(не выполняет.)

  }
        f = fopen("bd2.txt", "a+");//Для перехода в конец.
        if(!f)
                 puts("ERROR"), exit(1);
        word = strtok(buff, delim);//В нашей ситуации не нужно
        Num = atoi (word); //Вот только atoi надо использовать с f как-то
        fprintf(f, "%s\n ", word);
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
        fclose(f);
        return 0;
}
```

//Выполняет только buff, пытался через atoi что-то сделать, но у меня программа //дальше не работает.

//В этой программе будет бесконечный цикл т.к. неправильно задал 
//переменные(Скорее всего)  Но я не знаю как исправить.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//У программы бесконечный цикл, скорее всего. Ибо зависла.
int main(void)
{
        char buff[] = "0";
        char delim[] = "|";
        //char *word;
        int Num=0;//Список ID с 0 и по возрастающей.Дважды обьявляю?
        int i=0;//Чтоб программа потом выполнялась только 1 раз
        int k=1;//Аналогично
        FILE *f;
        if ((f = fopen("bd2.txt", "a+"))==NULL)
  {
     fprintf(f, "%d\n", Num);//но.....нет.

  }
        f = fopen("bd2.txt", "a+");//Для перехода в конец.
        if(!f)
                 puts("ERROR"), exit(1);
      //  word = strtok(buff, delim);//оставит до разделителя инфу.
        Num = atoi (buff);
        if (Num=0)//Хотел сделать на случай самого первого ID
        {
        for(int Num=0; Num<1; Num++)
        fprintf(f, "%d\n ", Num);
        fclose(f);
        }
        else //И на случай остальных ID, основная программа.
        {
          //Неверный цикл, я неправильно написал.(переменная k)
        for(int Num=k; Num>=1; i++)
        fprintf(f, "%d\n ", Num);
        Num=Num+1;
        }
        //  word = strtok(NULL, delim);
        k=k+1;
        fclose(f);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if ((f = fopen("bd2.txt", "a+"))==NULL)
  {
     fprintf(f, "%d\n", Num);//но.....нет.

  }` - В переводе на русский: если файл **НЕ** открылся, запишем в него...

Answer (score 0):

Мне лень выписывать полный код этой ф-ции, поэтому изображу на псевдокоде:

```
 1. Инициализация переменных
    N = 0;
    string = '';
 2. Считываем начальное значение N
    2.1. Открываем файл в режиме "r"
    2.2. Цикл до конца файла
         2.2.1. Читаем очередную строку
         2.2.2. Если не EOF, запоминаем её в string.
    2.3. Прочитана последняя строка, N = atoi(string);
    2.4. Закрываем файл
 3. N++;
 4. Записываем в файл
    4.1. Открываем файл в режиме "a"
    4.2. fprintf(Файл, N)
 5. Закрываем файл и выходим из функции
```